Instance of object without implementing an interface
I have a code sample that defines a Worker interface and an Employee class that does not implement that interface. In my main method, I declare a Worker called w and instantiate it as an Employee.
This compiles and runs just fine, which confuses me. How is it possible to create a new Employee object as a Worker without implementing it?
public interface Worker {
    void work(double a);
}

public class Employee {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public static void test(double a) {
        System.out.println("Number : " + a);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Worker w = Employee::test;
         w.work(12);
    }
}


The interface has only a single method, thus it is a fuctional interface and can be implemented by a lambda. The lambda IS the "object" you are looking for.

do you mean this is lambda feature ?

Your question does not make any sense. Please explain a bit more what you actually want. You can implement the interface Worker without implementing any class: Worker w = a -> a * 2; or even Worker w = a -> {System.out.println("Worker working..."); return a * 2;};. But why would you then need Employee in your code or let Employee implement Worker? I think you're mixing up some things there. Please fix your question.

@JayC667 , i only read same code in linkedin community , i only confused about that !

(Deleted all my comments as the implementation bit of the spec is at least somewhere indicative. I still think it's clearer for communication to separate the two and keep that connection as only an implementation detail though.)

There are no instances of Employee created at all. You're using a method reference to implement the Worker interface, which is a functional interface due to only having a single abstract method.
The Employee::test method reference (the overload accepting a double parameter) satisfies that functional interface, so the conversion from the method reference to the functional interface succeeds.

I'd like to add that the method reference expression evaluates the an object which implements the target interface (Worker). So the interface IS implemented.
